# How to invite Facebook friends to use my application?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I want to invite Facebook friend to use iPhone app. I did lots of search and found solutions but unfortunately I have some doubts regarding this.

1) May I invite all the friends from Facebook to use the app

2) May I need to submit iPhone app on Facebook to get all the Facebook friends

Answer (score 0):

There is a very details explanation on how to invite friends to your App in the Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

In your case (iOS App), the message dialog is the appropriate way to invite friends.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer.I have one question may I fetch all the friends of logged in user from Facebook?

Comment: Currently i could not able to get all the friends from Facebook in ios app to share app.

Comment: no, you can only fetch the friends who authorized your app too. only if your app is a game, you can use this, but only for inviting users: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/invitable_friends

Comment: Thanks luschn for detail answer. Actually i want to integrate invite friends functionality with ios app not game app so which is the ideal way to do so.And again thanks.

Comment: as i said in my answer, the message dialog

Comment: Thanks luschn again.I have downloaded samples from Facebook developer site and tried to invite Friends which authorised my app but unfortunately i could not see any notification in invited user account.Is there another changes we need to do?

Comment: as i said, use the message dialog. not sure what you are doing right now, app requests/invites are for games on canvas only.

Comment: Finally i could request to particular user to use my app but it shows me in Games->Activity->Invites.This is not what I actually want.I have used [FBWebDialogs
     presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil...] this method to invite Friends.

Comment: that´s becuase those invites are for games, not for apps. again, don´t use app requests and read my answer. it´s all in there.

Comment: Finally i'm able to invite FB Friends and also getting notification in notification area.I didn't added canvas url for facebook app,now I added canvas url in facebook app developer account and works for me.Getting those requests immediately.

Comment: i guess it does not matter for you if i tell you: don´t add canvas if you don´t use canvas ;)

Comment: When canvas url was not added at that time request was showing in games->section instead notification area.After adding canvas url i'm able to see request in notification area.

Comment: yeah, but you are not supposed to use app requests for non canvas and non game apps. that´s the main point, see the link in my answer.